# Row-major multiplication multithreading in C

Tags: c, multithreading, matrix

I have gone through all over google to find the logic behind row-major and column-major but did not seem to find answer for my question.
My question is:
I have three types of dimensions of matrices, say; *5x50000*, *500x500*, *50000x5*. All three will have same multilplications of 250000. However, when these multiplications are done in row-major, why *5x50000* matrix is taking the highest time to execute? I know this is something to do with cache. My machine has got L1 32K, L2 256k, L3 8192k.

Upon googling and reading some answers, I understood that arrays in C program are stored in contiguous making row-major fastest, but my question is what it has to do with *5x50000* matrix making it the worst? Is it because it has got large column? and *500x500* making the best?

Any explanation is much helpful. 
Thanks.

Comment: As far as I remember, to multiply two matrices M1 and M2, the number of cols in M1 should be equal to the number of rows in M1.

Comment: Yes ofcourse! I have specified the dimensions (rowxcol) of the matrices in the question. In my code, the logic is A[i][j] = A[i*n + j] where i and j are the row index and col index of matrix A and n being the number of columns. This is the row-major multiplication.

Comment: In what order are you multiplying the three matrices?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, arrays are stored in blocks on memory. If you request a big array, the PC will look for all that space at once. And it will try to make the array continuous in memory at the same time.

Demanding an array of 50000 slots 5 times its super time-wasting due to memory allocation. For the computer,its easier to find 500 continuous slots in memory 500 times.

Comment: Okay, so in that case, I assume even 50000x5 should produce the worst case, but it did not. Why is that so?

Comment: no! The worst case is 5x50000 because the PC will try to find 5 spaces of 50000 slots. At 50000x5 the computer is looking for 50000 spaces of 5 slots. It is easy to locate lots of small spaces in a memory plenty of other stuff...